# How to accept a generic argument to override the return type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Now I have a function called `useUrl`, as the code in `useTest` shows, it works well with the `obj`

I want to change it to accept a generic argument to override the default return type, how to do that?

(Please notice this is mainly about changing the TS type definition, not JS logic)

```
const useUrl = <K extends string>(keys: K[]) => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  return qs.parse(searchParams.toString()) as { [key in K]: string };
};

const useTest = () => {
  const obj = useUrl(["name", "age"]); // the type of obj is: {name: string, age: string} 

  // how to change the type definition of above useUrl function make it can do this thing?
  const objWithNumberAge = useUrl<{ age: number }>(["name", "age"]); // the type of objWithNumberAge is expected to be: {name: string, age: number}
};
```

Comment: Can you please write one snippet that can execute here so that, I can edit it for solution!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you want to accomplish.

> I want to change it to accept a generic argument to override the default return type, how to do that?

Just to make sure we are on the same page. The type you write inside `<>` is not the return type, but a type definition (which is your Generic). If you want to define a return type, you have to do it at the end of the signature (see below answer)

Now, I think you want to make the return type of the method to be what you defined inside the `<>`, and The argument's type can be whatever. If that is the case, you can do the following which will make the two examples you provided work at least.

```
const useUrl = <K extends string | object>(keys: string[]): K => {}
```

We are now returning the same type as what we define inside the `<>`, but we always pass a string of keys as the argument.

If you can provide some more examples, or formulate your question differently, it might be easier to help.